# ASP.NET include file on Page_Load

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I have created ASP.NET intranet site which has a code to check the user access levels for each page. This code is placed on Page_Load event of every page where restrictions in required.

Following code is placed on every pages where only Admin & Catering staff should have access to:

```
    public partial class cat_suppliers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_employee where emp_uname = @UserName", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", User.Identity.Name);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dr["emp_role"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    lblmessage.Text = "Admin";
                }
                else if (dr["emp_role"].ToString() == "3")
                {
                    lblmessage.Text = "Catering";
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Only Catering staff are authorized to access this page!!!')</script>");
                    Response.Write("<script>window.location.href='default.aspx';</script>");
                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Following code is placed on every pages where only Admin & Marketing staff should have access to:

```
    public partial class mar_contractors : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_employee where emp_uname = @UserName", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", User.Identity.Name);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dr["emp_role"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    lblmessage.Text = "Admin";
                }
                else if (dr["emp_role"].ToString() == "2")
                {
                    lblmessage.Text = "Marketing";
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Only Marketing staff are authorized to access this page!!!')</script>");
                    Response.Write("<script>window.location.href='default.aspx';</script>");
                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can put the common code in the separate file and include it in the Page_Load event ? Like following for the Catering pages.

```
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_employee where emp_uname = @UserName", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", User.Identity.Name);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dr["emp_role"].ToString() == "1")
            {
                lblmessage.Text = "Admin";
            }
            else if (dr["emp_role"].ToString() == "3")
            {
                lblmessage.Text = "Catering";
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Only Catering staff are authorized to access this page!!!')</script>");
                Response.Write("<script>window.location.href='default.aspx';</script>");
            }
        }

        con.Close();
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Create a method which returns `DataTable` and call the method in your `Page_Load` event. What's stopping you?

Comment: Make a common function of type `DataTable` that is accessible through out your site. Now you can call this method at `Page_Load`.

Comment: The first and third codeblocks are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to use Page Inheritance In ASP.NET. Following link will Help you getting the same.
[Page Inheritance](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8589/Page-Inheritance-In-ASP-NET)